# SQLite store current date with time set by defaut to 00:00:00

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, unix-timestamp

I have a SQLite table which one of its columns is:

```
timestamp long DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

It stores in database the UTC date and time but also the time. As time is not important for me how can I store it with time set to 00:00:00 by defaut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
timestamp long DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL
```

By the way - do you know that this format is stored as text (as you may see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html))?
 In many cases, especially when you have reason to index this field, it's more efficient to use INTEGER and just take care and put low-level long date/time representation when inserting/updating

Answer (score 1):

The [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) allow to modify a date value in the way you want:

```
timestamp text DEFAULT (date('now', 'start of day')) NOT NULL
```

If you want to store the value as a number, you can convert it appropriately:

```
timestamp long DEFAULT (strftime('%s', 'now', 'start of day')) NOT NULL
```